# Get advance custom field image

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i'm trying to get the object image that i inserted with acf. But the problem is: the code always return an array with only one index, that return a number (i think it's the id).

[image]

Comment: you can set the ACF field to either return an ID of the image, or the object.

Comment: I set the ACF to return an object, but he always return an id

Comment: how you are calling the field in template?

Comment: foto-d-5, then i use get_field('foto-d-5') in the code

Comment: `$img = get_field('foto-d-5');` is returning an id?? it shouldn't!

Comment: as per your call, it will gives object only, are you sure that you have initialized the foto-d-5 only once in custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image field to return a URL, save the field group, set it back to "object" and save it again to see if works.

(I think somethimes the correct return format is not properly saved in the database for reasons I don't know)

If you are in development and it won't affect content already uploaded to that field, try deleting the field and recreating it.

This has happened to me to me from time to time during development and those "fixes" usually work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php 

    $image = get_field('foto-d-5');

    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```